# Added into database list of id in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this list of id

```
"recipients"=>"1702356,1702328,1702329,1702357,1702358,1702359,1702331,1702332,1702360,1714240,1702361,1702363,1702364,1702334,1718481,1702336,1714996,1702337,1702365,1714289,1718984,1702338,1702340,1702367,1702341,1702343,1702345,1702368,1702369,1702370,1702346,1702348,1702350,1702352,1702371,1714998,1702372,1702354,1718763"
```

This list not fix, where i choose students i receive as parameter list of id.
I want add each id in database as following :

```
   @recipient = params[:recipients]
        @recipient.each do |k|   
    @recipient = Recipient.create(:e_id => @id, :r_id =>k, :td_id =>@f, :student_id =>k, :s_id =>@current_user.s_id )  
            logger.info "recipient added ... 123456789"
            end
```

Not working added only 1 id and print in log 1 `"recipient added ... 123456789"`

What wrong in my code?

Comment: Considering the context you gave in the question, `recipients` is a string, you may have to turn it into an array before iterate on that. Try to replace `@recipient.each` with @recipient.split(',').each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `recipient` list is a string that you need to split into individual ids first:

```
@recipients = params[:recipients].split(',').map do |student_id|  
   Recipient.create(
     e_id: @id, 
     r_id: k, 
     td_id: @f, 
     student_id: student_id, 
     s_id: @current_user.s_id 
   )  
   logger.info "recipient added ... #{student_id}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following for bulk insert to reduce # of inserts fired as I see there are lot of studentIDs. This will fire only 1 insert Query to store all records.

```
columns = %w(e_id r_id td_id student_id s_id)
values = []
params[:recipients].split(',').map do |student_id|
  values << [@id, k, @f, student_id, @current_user.s_id]
end
Recipient.import(columns, values)
```

Note: Add `gem "activerecord-import"` to your `Gemfile`